# How to install the go package: gencodec?

Tags: go, package

Basically, the title of the question. I am new to developing with the Go programming language, and I am getting this error when trying to install this specific package: gencodec

```
go install gencodec@latest: malformed module path "gencodec": missing dot in first path element
```

This is pretty much the only documentation I could find on it, and it doesn't provide a tutorial on how to install it.

[Click here for the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/fjl/gencodec?utm_source=godoc)

Is installing packages via go similar to using npm? I come from a javascript background so I am not entirely sure if I am even doing it correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you want to create a type structure.
I read in the documentation you provided, you will need to build the gencode binary. [gencode repository](https://github.com/fjl/gencodec)

Try downloading the gencode repository content, into the execute `go build` folder, then you will have a binary gencode ... after that run `gencodec -type MyType -formats json, yaml, toml -out mytype_json.go`

Comment: Yes! I basically just want to be able to run the command `gencodec` through my terminal. Just cloning the repo content into the build folder and running `go build` will allow me to do this? Do I need to maybe set any system environment variables?

Comment: Yes, with content of this repo you can run `go build` and create a binary of gencode, then you can use the command just like gencode documentation.
1. Clone repo; 2. Go inside folder of gencode; 3. run go build; 4. use a binary gencode